# how to access parent document from html object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

this is about HTML `<object>` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>parent</title>
  <style>
    #square { width:20px; height:20px; background-color: aqua;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="square"></div>
  <object data="child.html" type="text/html" ></object>
</body>
</html>
```

and **child.html** is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <button>red</button>
  <button>blue</button>

  <script>
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(bt=>{
      bt.onclick=e=>{
        console.log(e.target.textContent)
        document.parentNode.getElementById('square').style.background = e.target.textContent
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

but I got this error :

> TypeError: document.parentNode is null

so how to access to #square element from child.html in JS ?

Comment: I think you are searching for this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp

Comment: I think this is not possible with only JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
parent.document.getElementById('square').style.background = e.target.textContent
```

Comment: I think this is a solution but I got this error : `SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object` and everything is only on my local small computer...

Comment: It works for me, may be because of your file locations and how you are accessing them causing that issue.

Comment: are you accessing files through any server, may be local server?

Comment: no, this only 2 local files on my computer, as `file:///home/me/test/parent.html` and `file:///home/me/test/child.html`. Firefox or Chromium. (linux)

Comment: and how are you running your application?

Comment: in your file system symply use right click = " open your document in FireFox "

Comment: I am doing the same thing.